# RSS '<link>' Tag in Jade

Tags: rss, pug

For my blog site, I use Node.js, Express, and Jade for templating.

I built a simple rss.jade template for my RSS feed, and am having problems getting the required  tag to work nicely.

I believe, in older versions of Jade you could use:

```
link http://example.com
```

Now, it is enforcing that 'link' is self-closing like:

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='style.css')
```

Is there any other solution rather than plain-text like:

```
|<link>http://example.com</link>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you defined the right doctype?

With the `doctype xml` you can produce this **example**:

```
doctype xml
rss(version="2.0")
  link.
    http://example.com
```

and get the **output** you wished to see:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0">
  <link>http://example.com</link>
</rss>
```